# How can I download a free copy of Battlefield 1943?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3, battlefield-1943

Anyone know how to download the free BF1943 game on PS3?  I read the following on Wikipedia,

> Shortly after EA was threatened with being taken to court over its failure to deliver the free game BF1943, as announced at E3, EA announced they will offer owners of the PlayStation 3 version of Battlefield 3 a free downloadable copy of Battlefield 1943.

Comment: Just to be clear: do you own Battlefield 3 for PS3?

Answer (score 1):

The downloadable version of Battlefield 1943 is located on the playstation store. All you have to do is type it in the search bar.